# go array is stored as a string - how to convert to array

Tags: go

I have this list as a string:

["test1","test2"]

How do I convert?  From my limited understanding this is an interface:

```
[]interface{}
```

if so then how do I convert to an array?

```
fmt.Println(test)
["test1", "test2"]

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(test))
string
```

I tried the below:

```
in := []byte(test)
var raw []interface{}
json.Unmarshal(in, &raw)
fmt.Println(raw[0])
```

the above worked fyi

Thanks

Comment: That appears to be a valid JSON representation of an array of strings, so you could use [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json).

Comment: So you have something like `str := "[\"test1\",\"test2\"]"`, or `str := []string{"test1","test2"}`?

Comment: i have exactly what I posted

Comment: If you have a string, it's a string, not an "interface". If the string contains valid json, you could unmarshal that into into a `[]interface{}`, or a `[]string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json as a list of string will decode using a golang list of strings

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    test := `["test1","test2"]`
    in := []byte(test)
    var raw []string
    json.Unmarshal(in, &raw)
    fmt.Println(raw[0])
}
```